# Searching values in matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to resolve one task with matrix. I have function: fill_area(matrix, coordinates, value). If I would input coordinates for example (1,0) and value 3, it should write 3 in position [1][0] and rewrite the value to 3. If near numbers have the same value, it should also rewrite them. I would like to use an stack or queue for numbers, which have to change an value.
But I have no idea, how to check all nearest position.

```
matrix = [[2, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 1],
          [0, 1, 1]]

fill_area(matrix, (1, 0), 3)

matrix = [[2, 0, 1],
         [3, 3, 1],
         [3, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to handle matrices is numpy but there seems to be no obvious way to handle this special case while avoiding loops over items in numpy. I take it from your example that you define "nearness" as the patch around the given coordinates but in coordinate-direction only. I have two versions, one for the entire coordinate-patch around the given coordinates, the other in ij-direction only (per your example). Both are list comprehensions, for better readability you might want to change that to regular loops.

```
def fill_area(mat, ij, val):
    '''set patch around ij in mat to val for all positions where the original mat value == mat val at ij, full patch''' 
    return [[val if abs(i-ij[0])<2 and abs(j-ij[1])<2 and mat[i][j] == mat[ij[0]][ij[1]] 
             else mat[i][j] for j in range(len(mat[1]))] for i in range(len(mat))]

def fill_area1(mat, ij, val):
    '''set patch around ij in mat to val for all positions where the original mat value == mat val at ij, patch ij-dir''' 
    return [[val if ((abs(i-ij[0])<2 and j==ij[1]) or (abs(j-ij[1])<2 and i==ij[0])) and mat[i][j] == mat[ij[0]][ij[1]] 
             else mat[i][j] for j in range(len(mat[1]))] for i in range(len(mat))]

matrix = [[2, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 1],
          [0, 1, 1]]

print('entire patch: ', fill_area(matrix, (1, 0), 3))
print('ij-directional: ', fill_area1(matrix, (1, 0), 3))
```

which produces

```
entire patch:  [[2, 3, 1], [3, 3, 1], [3, 1, 1]]
ij-directional:  [[2, 0, 1], [3, 3, 1], [3, 1, 1]]
```